# Repeating elements in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am a C++ student. And I need to solve this problem: "Write a program that receives a number and an array of the size of the given number. The program must find all the duplicates of the given numbers, push-back them to a vector of repeating elements, and print the vector". The requirements are I'm only allowed to use the vector library and every repeating element of the array must be pushed to the vector only once, e.g. my array is "1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4...", the vector must be "1 ,2".
Here's what I've done so far. My code works, but I'm unable to make it add the same duplicate to the vector of repeating elements only once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  int* arr = new int[n];
  std::vector<int> repeatedElements;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::cin >> arr[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    bool foundInRepeated = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < repeatedElements.size(); ++j) {
      if(arr[i] == repeatedElements[j]) {
        foundInRepeated = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(foundInRepeated) {
      continue;
    } else {
      for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int count = 1;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
          if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {
            ++count;
          }
        }
        if(count > 1) {
          repeatedElements.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < repeatedElements.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << repeatedElements[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Which part of "before adding a value to a vector search it and make sure it's not already there" do you have a question about? The code you showed in your question demonstrates that you know how to search a vector for a value. So, what exactly are you unclear about, about simply searching another vector for a given value, before deciding whether to add the value to it (when you didn't find it)?

Comment: Tip: Instead of writing `int* arr = new int[n]`, you could use a vector as well: `std::vector<int> arr; arr.resize(n);` In the long run, the 2min time investment to skim over `std::vector` documentation will pay off.

Comment: If you don't want repeated elements in your container, then perhaps use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (or [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) if ordering is not important) instead?

Comment: Hint: Check what `std::sort` can do for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what you're doing here:

```
if(foundInRepeated) {
      continue;
    } else {
      for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  // why?
```

If the element at some index `i` (from the outer loop) is not found in `repeatedElements`, you're again iterating through the entire array, and adding elements that are repeated. But you already have an `i` that you're interested in, and hasn't been added to the `repeatedElements`. You only need to iterate through `j` in the `else` branch.

Removing the line marked `why?` (and the closing brace), will solve the problem. Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E3M3jG).

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to follow a plan. Divide the bigger problem into a sequence of smaller problems is a good start. While this often does not yield an optimal solution, at least it yields a solution, which is more or less straightforward. And which subsequently can be optimized, if need be.

1. How to find out, if a number in the sequence has duplicates?
   We could brute force this:
   `is_duplicate i = arr[i+1..arr.size() - 1] contains arr[i]`
   and then write ourselves a helper function like

```
bool range_contains(std::vector<int>::const_iterator first, 
                    std::vector<int>::const_iterator last, int value) { 
// ... 
}
```

and use it in a simple

```
for (auto iter = arr.cbegin(); iter != arr.cend(); ++iter) { 
  if (range_contains(iter+1, arr.cend(), *iter) && !duplicates.contains(*iter)) { 
    duplicates.push_back(*iter); 
  } 
}
```

But this would be - if I am not mistaken - some O(N^2) solution.
As we know, sorting is O(N log(N)) and if we sort our array first, we will
have all duplicates right next to each other. Then, we can iterate over the sorted array once (O(N)) and we are still cheaper than O(N^2). (O(N log(N)) + O(N) is still O(N log(N))).

> 1 2 1 2 3 4 => sort => 1 1 2 2 3 4

Eventually, while using what we have at our disposal, this could yield to a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using IntVec = std::vector<int>;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    IntVec arr; // aka: input array
    IntVec duplicates; 

    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    // Read n integers from std::cin
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(arr), n,
            [](){
                return *(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin));
            });
    // sort the array (in ascending order).
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()); // O(N*logN)
    auto current = arr.cbegin();
    while(current != arr.cend()) {
        // std::adjacent_find() finds the next location in arr, where 2 neighbors have the same value.
        current = std::adjacent_find(current,arr.cend());
        if( current != arr.cend()) {
            duplicates.push_back(*current);
            // skip all duplicates here
            for( ; current != (arr.cend() - 1) && (*current == *(current+1)); current++) {
            }
        }
    }
    // print the duplicates to std::cout
    std::copy(duplicates.cbegin(), duplicates.cend(), 
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```